# Algorithm for extracting first and last lines from sectionalized output file

Tags: python, algorithm, pytest

I am trying to parse the FAILURES section from the terminal output of a Pytest session, line by line, identifying the testname and test filename for each test, which I then want to append together to form a "fully qualified test name" (FQTN), e.g. `tests/test_1.py::test_3_fails`. I also want to get and save the traceback info (which is what is between the testname and the test filename).

The parsing part is straightforward and I already have working regex's that match the test name and the test filename, and I can extract the traceback info based on that. My issue with the FQTNs is algorithmic - I can't seem to figure out the overall logic to identify a testname, then the test's filename, wihch occurs on a later line. I need to accommodate for not only the tests that are in the middle of the FAILURES section, but also the first test and the last test of the FAILURES section.

Here's an example. This is the output section for all failures during a test run, along with some of the terminal output that comes right before FAILURES, and right after.

```
.
.
.
============================================== ERRORS ===============================================
__________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_c_error ___________________________________

    @pytest.fixture
    def error_fixture():
>       assert 0
E       assert 0

tests/test_2.py:19: AssertionError
============================================= FAILURES ==============================================
___________________________________________ test_3_fails ____________________________________________

log_testname = None

    def test_3_fails(log_testname):
>       assert 0
E       assert 0

tests/test_1.py:98: AssertionError
--------------------------------------- Captured stdout setup ---------------------------------------
Running test tests.test_1...
Running test tests.test_1...
Setting test up...
Setting test up...
Executing test...
Executing test...
Tearing test down...
Tearing test down...
---------------------------------------- Captured log setup -----------------------------------------
INFO     root:test_1.py:68 Running test tests.test_1...
INFO     root:test_1.py:69 Setting test up...
INFO     root:test_1.py:70 Executing test...
INFO     root:test_1.py:72 Tearing test down...
______________________________________ test_8_causes_a_warning ______________________________________

log_testname = None

    def test_8_causes_a_warning(log_testname):
>       assert api_v1() == 1
E       TypeError: api_v1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'log_testname'

tests/test_1.py:127: TypeError
--------------------------------------- Captured stdout setup ---------------------------------------
Running test tests.test_1...
Running test tests.test_1...
Setting test up...
Setting test up...
Executing test...
Executing test...
Tearing test down...
Tearing test down...
---------------------------------------- Captured log setup -----------------------------------------
INFO     root:test_1.py:68 Running test tests.test_1...
INFO     root:test_1.py:69 Setting test up...
INFO     root:test_1.py:70 Executing test...
INFO     root:test_1.py:72 Tearing test down...
___________________________ test_16_fail_compare_dicts_for_pytest_icdiff ____________________________

    def test_16_fail_compare_dicts_for_pytest_icdiff():
        listofStrings = ["Hello", "hi", "there", "at", "this"]
        listofInts = [7, 10, 45, 23, 77]
        assert len(listofStrings) == len(listofInts)
>       assert listofStrings == listofInts
E       AssertionError: assert ['Hello', 'hi... 'at', 'this'] == [7, 10, 45, 23, 77]
E         At index 0 diff: 'Hello' != 7
E         Full diff:
E         - [7, 10, 45, 23, 77]
E         + ['Hello', 'hi', 'there', 'at', 'this']

tests/test_1.py:210: AssertionError
____________________________________________ test_b_fail ____________________________________________

    def test_b_fail():
>       assert 0
E       assert 0

tests/test_2.py:27: AssertionError
============================================== PASSES ===============================================
___________________________________________ test_4_passes ___________________________________________
--------------------------------------- Captured stdout setup ---------------------------------------
Running test tests.test_1...
Running test tests.test_1...
Setting test up...
Setting test up...
Executing test...
Executing test...
Tearing test down...
Tearing test down...
.
.
.
```

Is anyone here good with algorithms, maybe some pseudo code that shows an overall way of getting each testname and its associated test filename?

Comment: Does it have to be this complicated (parsing the terminal output)? What is the actual goal you are trying to achieve? If you need to know the node names of failed tests with the exception stacktraces, this can be retrieved easily by a small local plugin, where you can then postprocess the gained data if necessary.

Comment: That's a fair question. What I'm trying to do is correlate a unique testname w/ its ANSI-coded traceback so I can display it in a text user interface (part of a Pytest plugin I've written). My current code doesn't accommodate the same test names in different source files. The plugin works in the unique-testname case; I'm trying to leverage that work, but it's turning ugly; maybe I need to rethink things. Parsing terminal output is a PITA but I can't use Pytest's junit feature because it does not support all test outcomes, like Xpass/Xfail. Source: https://github.com/jeffwright13/pytest-tui

Comment: I see. Still, I wouldn't touch the terminal output since it's a subject to change and you might end in a situation of maintaining several sets of regular expressions for several major pytest versions. You can access and store the report data prepared for terminal rendering though, and then render it yourself. E.g. if you check out `pytest_runtest_logreport`, it’s `report` arg gives you the unique nodename of the test via `report.nodeid` and the stack trace as a list of preindented lines via `report.longrepr`.

Comment: With that, you can reuse `TerminalReporter` to render output chunks in `pytest` style, or have something custom (using `rich` etc).

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now, but I can think of a minimal working example in the evening to illustrate the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had discovered the `TestReport` object and its `nodeid` attribute through my time in the debugger on this project  :-)  as well as `longrepr` - I just didn't have any idea how to get the stack trace info re-rendered into ANSI because calls to `TerminaWriter`'s `markup` function require `**kwargs` to specify color/bold/etc. So it felt like I was recreating what was already available to me in the terminal output.

Definitely open to new ideas. If I could cut the code I have that deals with parsing terminal output I would probably reduce LOCs by 50%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proposal to get the rendered summary for a test case report. Use this stub as a rough idea - you might want to iterate through the reports and dump the rendered summaries first, then do the curses magic to display the collected data.

Some tests to play with:

```
import pytest


def test_1():
    assert False


def test_2():
    raise RuntimeError('call error')


@pytest.fixture
def f():
    raise RuntimeError('setup error')


def test_3(f):
    assert True


@pytest.fixture
def g():
    yield
    raise RuntimeError('teardown error')


def test_4(g):
    assert True
```

Dummy plugin example that renders the summary for `test_3` case. Put the snippet in `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    # example: get rendered output for test case `test_spam.py::test_3`

    # get the reporter
    reporter = config.pluginmanager.getplugin('terminalreporter')

    # create a buffer to dump reporter output to
    import io

    buf = io.StringIO()
    # fake tty or pytest will not colorize the output
    buf.isatty = lambda: True

    # replace writer in reporter to dump the output in buffer instead of stdout
    from _pytest.config import create_terminal_writer

    # I want to use the reporter again later to dump the rendered output,
    # so I store the original writer here (you probably don't need it)
    original_writer = reporter._tw
    writer = create_terminal_writer(config, file=buf)
    # replace the writer
    reporter._tw = writer

    # find the report for `test_spam.py::test_3` (we already know it will be an error report)
    errors = reporter.stats['error']
    test_3_report = next(
        report for report in errors if report.nodeid == 'test_spam.py::test_3'
    )

    # dump the summary along with the stack trace for the report of `test_spam.py::test_3`
    reporter._outrep_summary(test_3_report)

    # print dumped contents
    # you probably don't need this - this is just for demo purposes

    # restore the original writer to write to stdout again
    reporter._tw = original_writer
    reporter.section('My own section', sep='>')
    reporter.write(buf.getvalue())
    reporter.write_sep('<')
```

A `pytest` run now yields an additional section

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> My own section >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    @pytest.fixture
    def f():
>       raise RuntimeError('setup error')
E       RuntimeError: setup error

test_spam.py:14: RuntimeError
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

with the stack trace rendered same way `pytest` does in the `ERRORS` summary section. You can play with outcomes for different test cases if you want - replace the `reporter.stats` section if necessary (`errors` or `failed`, or even `passed` - although the summary should be empty for passed tests) and amend the test case `nodeid`.

Comment: Cool, I was able to use your code snippets to ANSI-encode `longreprtext`, then associate that string with the test's `nodeid` and display it in my TUI. GOod stuff, thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help! Take this answer with a grain of salt since it uses private methods of terminal reporter which are not guaranteed to be stable. Although from my experience the reporter never changed much, so it should be safe. Also, IMO it should still be easier to maintain than parsing the output :-)

Comment: FYI: I was able to pass the `buf.getvalue()` to the `ansi2html`-library, and get nice colored output to use for the web!